# Creating not printing a list for each

Tags: r, foreach

I want to do this:

```
for(i in 1:length(dlist)){
  rlist[[i]] <- rasterize(u[,c("Lon","Lat")], r, dlist[[i]], fun=mean)
}
```

Since I will have to do it over several files (the length of the list is around 300), I want to runt it each 4 files on parallel, so I tried this (just to get the first four).

```
cl=makeCluster(detectCores() - 2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
rlist = list()
foreach(i= 1:1, .packages="raster",.export=('rlist'),.combine= 'c') %dopar% {

 rlist[[i]] <- rasterize(u[,c("Lon","Lat")], r, dlist[[i]], fun=mean)
}
```

However, this prints a list in the console, and does not assign each rasterize to the ith element of the list, any ideas why? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
x <- foreach(i= 1:4, .packages="raster", .combine=stack) %dopar% {
    rasterize(u[,c("Lon","Lat")], r, dlist[[i]], fun=mean)
}
```

A simple example

```
library(raster)
library(foreach)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10, vals=1)
x <- foreach(i= 1:4, .packages="raster", .combine=stack) %do% { r + i }

s <- stack(x)
s 
#class       : RasterStack 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 100, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#names       : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3, layer.4 
#min values  :       2,       3,       4,       5 
#max values  :       2,       3,       4,       5
```

Or in one step

```
x <- foreach(i= 1:4, .packages="raster", .combine=stack) %do% { r + i }
```

But I think the simplest and most efficient approach might be to rasterize all variables in one step

```
 d <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(dlist)) 
 s <- rasterize(u[,c("Lon","Lat")], r, d, fun=mean)
```